# Horizontal submenus not showing

Tags: html, css

I have volunteered to design a pure css and html website for a non-profit organization whose board I sit on. I have successfully created a horizontal navigation bar and the rest of the site  but I can't get the sub menus to show, although I have spent hours watching youtube tutorials and trying to adapt answers to other similar questions on this site.

I want our submenus to look similar  the one at http://www.bgca.org/Pages/index.aspx (small-white letters, purple background and the length of the page (980px)).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/rsfavicon8.jpg" />
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <div id="ad">
      <center><img src="images/rsheader3.jpg" alt="Loading image..." class="featuredimage" /></center>
     </div></div><!--end ad-->

    <div class="div1">

    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="noborder leftedge">&nbsp;HOME&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&nbsp;ABOUT US&nbsp;</a></li>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOME1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOME1</a></li>
        </ul>   

    <li><a href="#">&nbsp;GET INVOLVED&nbsp;</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOME2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOME2</a></li>
        </ul>   

    <li><a href="#">&nbsp;EMPLOYMENT OPPORTUNITIES&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOME3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOME3</a></li>
        </ul>   

    <li><a href="#">&nbsp;CONTACT&nbsp;</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="rightedge">&nbsp;DONATE&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>




   </head>


  </body>
  </html>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

    @charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}

a.hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Arial" Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;  
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Arial" Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Arial" Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    color: black;
}

h3 {
    font-family: "Arial" Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color: black;
}
























/*Main CSS*/

html {
background-color: white;

}
.noborder {
    border-left-style: none !important;
}

.div1 ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.div1 ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #36c;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    border-left-width: thin;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #000;
}

.div1 ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #609;
}
.leftedge {
    border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
}
.rightedge {
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
}
.div1 ul {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 61em;
    }

.div1 ul ul {
     float: none;
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
     left: 0px;
     margin: -1px 0 0px 10px;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     }

.div1 ul ul:hover {
    display: block;
}

.div1 ul ul li {
position: static;
     float: none;
     display: inline;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
     background-color: #025179;
}

.div1 ul ul li a {
     display: inline;
     margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
     padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
     font-weight: normal;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: for starters, you have no head or body opening element and a /head closing element after your content, then some CSS scattered anywhere, then html content after the closing /body and /html. You have to re-write your entire code before it actually works or can be fixed

Comment: You don't have an opening `<head>` tag but you have a closing tag. Same for the `<body>` tag. And you have a bunch of CSS at the end of your HTML. It looks like your CSS should be in an external sheet and then referenced. I take it you're 100% new to development? Either way, you should definitely work on your code first.

EDIT: Just saw that @Fabio said just about the same thing. Clean up your code and then come back here; the community would be glad to help once it's legible.

Comment: All, sorry for the confusion - I just copied the relevant code for the nav bar but yes, the css is in an external stylesheet. I'm not new to web development, I designed my entire website from scratch using Dreamweaver (www.joebailey.info). Just very hung-up on these sub navigation menus lol...thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of syntax error and spelling mistakes in your code. Here I am going to give the solution for only on the menu part. You have to check other issues and other menu stylings.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="div1">

<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="noborder leftedge">&nbsp;HOME&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="#">&nbsp;ABOUT US&nbsp;</a>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME1</a></li>
    </ul>   
</li>
<li><a href="#">&nbsp;GET INVOLVED&nbsp;</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME2</a></li>
    </ul>   
</li>     

<li><a href="#">&nbsp;EMPLOYMENT OPPORTUNITIES&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME3</a></li>
    </ul>   
 </li> 
<li><a href="#">&nbsp;CONTACT&nbsp;</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="rightedge">&nbsp;DONATE&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1 ul {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 61em;
}

.div1 ul ul {
 float: none;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 left: 0px;
 margin: -1px 0 0px 10px;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 }

.div1 ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
.div1 ul ul li {
 float: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
 background-color: #025179;
}
 .div1 ul ul li a {
 margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
 padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 font-weight: normal;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
}
.div1 ul li
{
position:relative;    
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/maed360n/1/)